# How to make a scatterplot of unequal vectors (many to one)

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I plot a many-to-one scatter-graph?

I have a variable ACCN which is categorised into A and E then subcategorised into groups 1-4. I'd like to plot ACCN A vs ACCN E.

```
ACCN    TYPE    group
0.063506881 A   1
0.31137946  A   2
0.555806986 A   3
0.351273452 A   4
0.953185746 A   1
0.144960551 A   2
0.012836896 A   3
0.733213109 A   4
0.489181316 A   1
0.011568396 E   1
0.801788476 E   1
0.343939354 E   1
0.324220182 E   2
0.204721436 E   2
0.648309975 E   2
0.416937338 E   3
0.437851495 E   4
0.181315642 E   4
```

I think I'm looking for something like this:

```
plot(data$ACCN~data$TYPE+data$group)
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps the best thing to do would be replicate the values of A to fit the number of Es.

Comment: Ultimately I'm going to try to plot a line of best fit through the data points.This last bit seems straight forward summary(lm(data$ACCN~data$group+data$sample)). But it's plotting it out that's the tricky it...

Comment: Should `group` be coded as `numeric` or as a `factor`?

Comment: @bouncyball It should be as.factor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I would do is plot the values of your `data.frame` called `df`, and then draw a line representing the mean of the observations for each TYPE. We can do this using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(group), y = ACCN, group = TYPE, colour = TYPE))+
    geom_point(size = 1.5)+
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = 'line', size = 1.5)+
    theme_bw()+xlab('group')
```

[image]

The line is drawn via the `stat_summary` function.

Comment: Thank you, this is nice. Is it possible to put on errorbars+mean instead of the points and lines? Incidentally, I ended up replicating the data that was missing for A (by duplicating) to make equal length vectors. Not sure if this is a valid thing to do though?

Comment: @HCAI that would depend on your specific situation. check out `?stat_summary` to see other options you can use, `stat_summary(fun.data = 'mean_se')` might be useful